# How to prove double factorial sum: $\pi\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n-3}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}(n-k)=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

> $$\pi\cdot\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n-3}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}(n-k)=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2},\ \ \ \ n\in\Bbb{N}^+\tag1$$

I have a feeling that $(1)$ might be true. Contour integration yielded the LHS while the RHS is given in the answer key. To prove this result **without induction**, I first I distributed the sum, and showed that

$$\begin{align} n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}{n-k-1\choose n-k-1}\\&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+n-k-1}{2n\choose k}{-1\choose n-k-1}\\ &=n(-1)^{n-1}{2n-1\choose n-1}.\end{align}$$

I am not sure what to do with

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(-1)^k{2n\choose k}\tag2$$

since this has the additional $k$. I thought about using some definite integral substitutions for $k$ but those did not get me anywhere. A hint to solving $(2)$ ought to suffice though complete answers are also welcome.

**EDIT.** The original equality in $(1)$ does not hold. I had messed up the denominator. The correct identity is

> $$\pi\cdot\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}(n-k)=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}\frac{\pi}{2},\ \ \ \ n\in\Bbb{N}^+\tag{1'}.$$

Thanks to [Felix Marin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85343/felix-marin) for pointing this out!

Comment: @FelixMarin You are correct! By accident, I wrote the demominator on the LHS as $2^{2n-3}$ while it should stand as $2^{2n-1}$. Then the identity holds. I will not edit the title nor the question body (since you provided an answer for the existing LHS) but will add a small PS-edit to the end. Thanks!

Comment: That's fine. $\left)\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {\huge \smile}\right($.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ k\binom{2n}{k} = \frac{(2n)!}{(k-1)!(2n-k)!} = 2n\binom{2n-1}{k-1} $$

hence it follows that:

$$ A(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k(-1)^k \binom{2n}{k} = 2n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k \binom{2n-1}{k-1} = -2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k \binom{2n-1}{k} $$
and you already know how to deal with the last sum by exploiting symmetry.

---

An alternative comes from experience: the RHS of your identity is clearly related with integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2n}\,dx$. So we may start considering that

$$(e^{it}-e^{-it})^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}e^{(2n-k)it}e^{-kit}(-1)^k $$
differentiate both sides with respect to $t$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(2i\sin t\right)^{2n} = 2i\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^k(n-k)e^{(2n-2k)it} $$
then isolate the contributes given by $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ by multiplying both sides by $(e^{-2nit}+e^{-(2n-2)it}+\ldots+e^{-2it})$ (that is a simple geometric sum) and integrating over $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Nice and simple! Is there something I could call a sum of this kind to search for generalisations for where the $k$ in front is of higher (or lower) power? You are also right in your guess in the addendum, I was looking at the integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$.

Comment: @LinearChristmas: by Stirling numbers of the second kind any power of the form $k^r$ can be decomposed into a sum of binomial coefficients, for instance $k^2=2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}$, and the above "trick by shift" works in a similar way if $k$ is replaced by $\binom{k}{2},\binom{k}{3},\ldots$. That leads to a general approach. So, for short, have a look at Wikipedia about Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: And the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^{2n}(x)}{x^2}\,dx$ can be computed through integration by parts and a good number of techniques, like the Laplace transform, the residue theorem, Fourier inversion etc.

Comment: Yes, I performed integration by parts on a similar integral, this time opted for the residue theorem. I will definitely look into Stirling numbers. Thank you for your time! (Hopefully I didn't do a disservice by accepting the answer too quickly, not sure how the question popularity algorithms work here, might've robbed you of a few upvotes :-))

Comment: The OP answer ( in the RHS ) is wrong. The answer is ${\pi \over 2^{2n - 3}}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\pi\,{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2^{2n - 3}}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}{2n \choose k}\pars{n - k} =
> \require{cancel}\cancel{{\pars{2n - 3}!! \over \pars{2n - 2}!!}\,{\pi \over 2}}:\ {\large ?}\,,
> \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ >\ 0}}$.

$$
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\mbox{The RHS}\ correct\ answer\ \mbox{is}\quad 
{\pi \over 2^{2n - 3}}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}}
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}{2n \choose k}\pars{n - k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{n - k}{2n \choose 2n - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{n - k}\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{2n - k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{2n \choose 2n - k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{2n + 1}}
\overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{n - k}z^{k}}
^{\ds{{n \over 1 + z} + {z \over \pars{1 + z}^{2}} + \pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{z^{n + 1} \over \pars{1 + z}^{2}}}}\
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
n\
\underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 1} \over z^{2n + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{{2n - 1 \choose 2n}\ =\ 0}}\ +\
\underbrace{\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2} \over z^{2n}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}_{\ds{{2n - 2 \choose 2n - 1}\ =\ 0}}\ +\
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2} \over z^{n}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\pi\,{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over 2^{2n - 3}}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}{2n \choose k}\pars{n - k} =
{\pi \over 2^{2n - 3}}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}}
$$